# Set email sender in Landing Page via AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page, triggered-send

I'm sending out on email when a user lands on a landing page, described in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155513/trigger-email-from-landing-page-via-ampscript) post.

Now I would like to change the sender dynamically based on certain conditions. To do this I created a sender profile which uses variables in the FromEmail and FromName fields. Unfortunately tho, this seems to be ignored.

Sample from the landing page:

```
set @SenderEmail = Lookup('Ent.sender_DE', 'SenderEmail', 'parameter', @param)

And in the delivery profile settings I simply use this variable like so: <br>
%%=v(@SenderEmail)=%%
```

What am I missing to make it work? Or is there another way to simply set the sender via **AMPScript** in the landing page?

Comment: Hi Adam, can you confirm if you have "Dynamic Send Profile" provisioned from Salesforce Support; so allow for AMPScript in the send profile?

Comment: Is there an easy way to check it, or do I have to get in touch with support to do that?

Comment: Dynamic Send Profile allows you to do exactly as you've asked - the fact it's not working mean you may not have it activated. The Salesforce Support team will make quick work of it. In the mean time; try following [these steps](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/dynamic-sender-profile-with-ampscript), or [this tutorial](http://incrediblegorilla.com/2016/08/07/how-to-setup-dynamic-sender-profiles-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/). Neither is _exactly_ what you are doing, but both will teach you about how the function works.

Comment: Thanks, I get the general idea and I went through those.

But if I do as they do in the first example, where they assign a value to the @fromName variable and then use that in the sender profile's FromName field, it seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working simply by adding the field sender email field into the Data Extension the triggered send uses. After that instead of specifying the sender as %%=v(@SenderEmail)=%% I did it with the following syntax %%SenderEmail%% and it started working.

Still unclear for me tho, how can I use a variable in those fields unless it's not par of the underlying DE.

Answer (score 0):

It was providing the default from name and email address on your emails because the AMPscript variable was empty. Your issue is that you need the variable defined in the email, not just on the landing page for the dynamic sender profile to work. The dynamic sender profile pulls from the emails AMPscript, not the landing page.

The only way to control the from name directly from the Landing page is via a [triggered send API call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggeredsend.htm), in which case you can define the from name and address in the API call.

Alternatively, you can pass the variable into the email or have the lookup inside the email itself which should fill the AMPscript variable call you have in the sender profile.